# Function glob() not working with externe URL

Tags: php, function, ftp, client-server, glob

i'm confused with this problem 
when im working **locally** it's all fine 
with this :
 
 `foreach (glob("public/FolderA/B/") as $filename) {` 
  
but when i put

 `foreach (glob("http://www.exemple.com/public/FolderA/B/") as $filename) {`

doesn't work any solution ??? 

**History** : in the past i'm working with glob() and communicate with **local server** and the scripte do this jobs perfect now donne is **transfer**t to other server and problem i get is how to put glob() working **with external URL not locally** or some function has same functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**glob()** per definition finds pathnames matching a pattern.
This means that the function will not work on remote files as the diretory / files to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.

What you probably would need is accessing a remote filesystem thru an **FTP** server.

This is how it could look like:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");  // "." means the current directory
var_dump($contents);
```

Alternatively, if the previously local server still can be accessed, you could have a script on this server scan the directory as before and echo the file list (e.g. in XML or JSON format). This script could the be sent a request by the (now) remote script, giving the file list this way.

### Update: FTP Access, full script

```
<?php

$ftp_server   = 'ftp.example.org';
$ftp_port     = 21;
$ftp_timeout  = 90;
$ftp_user     = 'my_username';
$ftp_password = 'my_password';

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_port, $ftp_timeout);
if ($conn_id===false) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to the server<br />';
    exit(1);
}

// Log in or die
$logged_in = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_password);
if ($logged_in!==true) {
    echo 'Failed to log-in<br />';
    exit(1);
}

// Change directory if necessary
echo "Current directory: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . '<br />';

// Set to passive mode if required
ftp_pasv ($conn_id, true);

// Change directory if necessary
if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, 'subdir1/subdir2')) {
    echo "Current directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . '<br />';
} else {
    echo 'Could not change directory<br />';
    exit(1);
}

// Get list of files in this directory
$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
if ($files===false) {
    echo 'Failed to get listing<br />';
    exit(1);
}

foreach($files as $n=>$file) {
    echo "$n: $file<br />";
    $local_dir = '/my_local_dir/';
    foreach($files as $n => $file) {
        // These we don't want to download
        if (($file=='.') || ($file=='..') || ($file[0]=='.')) continue;
        // These we do want to download
        echo "$n: $file<br />";
        if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_dir.$file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
            echo "Successfully written to $local_dir$file<br />";
        } else {
            echo "Could not get $local_dir.$file<br />";
        }
    }
    // Do whatever has to been done with $file
}

?>
```

Comment: Yeah i using this method since two day ago but i still get a problem when i want to **foreach** a folder and get **ALL files** 
<br>
$filename = /home/Fto/www/test/public/data/module/111445
foreach ($filename as $file) {

Comment: Have you tried the code I proposed? What does the ***var_dump()*** display? Once you get the file list from the FTP server you surely can use a **foreach...** construct.

Comment: FTP is working everthing is right but when i foreach first in path and get all folder but when i want to foreach folder and got files '.txt' i can't do this 
'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'
but locally it's fine with glob() :/ 
@hherger

Comment: So, I have added a full script for accessing an FTP server, getting the listing of a directory, and downloading all the files from this directory. Of course, you could add a filter in order to download only the files you want. The result would be that you have the files locally as before.

Comment: ...and obviously you then could also use **glob()** as before.

Comment: i fixed by use 
`$file_liste = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, $filename);`
for every once i need foreach 
about the ideas for downloading to my locally i didn't used cuz that not working in my cas 
my last problem is **filemtime** doesn't work :/ 
_filemtime(): stat failed for http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/Test/public/data/module/111445/111445_2015-12-29.json_

Comment: The second parameter of the `ftp_nlist` function is a directory path relative to the one given by the FTP account you are using. Just a period `"."` means: the pre-defined directory.

Comment: Don't you get the files thru FTP? What exactly does not work in your case? And what problem do you have with `filemtime`. Do you use _filemtime_ locally or with a URL wrapper (e.g. `http://.....`)? BTW: The link `http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/Test/public/data/module/111445/111445_2015-12-29.json` can not be used.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP script is running under Windows, you can use

```
glob("\\\\remoteServer\\public\\FolderA\\B\\*.*")
```

because as hherger said "directory / files to be examined must be accessible via the server's file system." and Windows allows access to other PCs using a UNC path. Because Windows uses backslashes instead of forward slashes, and in PHP a backslash is an escape character, each backslash has to be preceded by a backslash. In Windows Explorer (aka File Explorer), the above UNC path would be

```
\\remoteServer\public\FolderA\B\*.*
```