# Alternative to glob php

Tags: php

I'm looking an alternative function to glob. I got this and it work perfectly.

```
<?php
$tipof = 'FACTURA';     
$cliente = '455928';
$files = glob("$cliente-$tipof*.pdf");
foreach ($files as $rows): ?>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;<?php echo end((explode('-', str_replace('.pdf','', $rows)))); ?> &nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;<?php echo $cliente ?> &nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;<?php echo "<a target=_blank href=\"".$rows."\">Ver</a>"; ?> &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

The file is in the project folder but how can I do if the file is in a URL? for example something like this: http://192.168.0.196:8080/pdf/

in that url my file is 455928-FACTURA-A106-8694-20171019.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a proper example of your use case? If it currently works, I see no need to change something

Comment: you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882114/function-glob-not-working-with-externe-url) is a good place to look for answers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `glob` over HTTP. `glob` depends on being able to read a list of all files in a directory. HTTP has no concept of "directories" and no standardised way of enumerating parts of a path. It just deals with *URLs*. URLs don't even have to correspond to *files* in any way. The URL `http://example.com/foo/bar` *could* be backed by a file, or the web server serving this URL could just create the response on the fly based on whatever it feels like. There is no way to enumerate *all possible URLs* when such URLs could just be made up on the fly, hence there's no way to `glob` over HTTP.

*Iﬀ* your web server happened to return a directory listing on the URL `http://192.168.0.196:8080/pdf/`, you could try parsing that.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are stored on a different machine not having access to the file system of that machine, I would create some sort of end-point (PHP would be fine) and call end-point via ajax in client or get response with CURL from php server-side, depends on your app needs. end-point would expose results as json to be consumed by your script. I would not go for the ftp or other means to expose file system. Take care of CORS if used in browser.

Answer (score 0):

## glob alternatives

So screen scraping is not the thing you are looking at. In the PHP world there are a couple of things that open a directory of folder and find all items inside.

### 1

[`opendir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) gets you a handle with which you can `readdir` to get the contents of a folder be it files or sub folders.

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

### DirctoryIterator

The [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class lets you do many more things but is basically a iterator you can use in a `foreach()` setting. Like this [recursive way](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php#128559) to zip an entire folder. Alledgely the DirectoryIterator is the fastes way to get you through a folder.